# How to connect to existing database Sqlite3 node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, bots, discord

Im making a discord bot and im using one package that uses sqlite3 and made a database.sqlite file. I want to start making other tables and using that database but i dont know how to connect to that database!
Please reply if you can help me also i use this package [discord-economy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-economy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question, but you can use [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) package from NPM.
Then, you would call your db file and check if db already exists. If not, you should create and run a new one. Otherwise you can just instantiate from your db file:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var fs = require('fs');
var dbFile = './database.sqlite';
var dbExists = fs.existsSync(dbFile);

if (!dbExists) {
    fs.openSync(dbFile, 'w');
}

var db = new sqlite3.Database(dbFile);

if (!dbExists) {
    db.run('CREATE TABLE `your_table` (' +
    '`id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,' +
    '`name` TEXT,' +
    '`email` TEXT,');
}

// You can insert some data here in order to test
// var statement = db.prepare('INSERT INTO `your_table` (`name`, `email`) ' +
'VALUES (?, ?)');

// statement.run('Your name', 'some_random@email.com');
// statement.finalize();

db.close();
```

Comment: and do you maybe know how to log a table in console?

Comment: console.table might do the job.

Comment: It's a plugin from npm btw.

Comment: So you write "new" even to open an existing database?